# How to install ChainerCV

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, chainercv

I am using Win 10. I tried installing ChainerCV through pip. I want to know what can be done to solve this problem. Also what is behind this issue: not having VisualStudio, dependency issues or any other thing. Is having CUDA necessary to run ChainerCV?

P.S I have chainer and other dependencies running properly.

**Stack Trace**:
copying chainercv\utils\bbox_nms_gpu_post.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\chainercv\utils\bbox
  running build_ext
  building 'chainercv.utils.bbox._nms_gpu_post' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

---

Failed building wheel for chainercv
  Running setup.py clean for chainercv
Failed to build chainercv
Installing collected packages: chainercv
  Running setup.py install for chainercv ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjghd97d\chainercv\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cl7d0zn_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

building 'chainercv.utils.bbox._nms_gpu_post' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjghd97d\chainercv\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cl7d0zn_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qjghd97d\chainercv\

Comment: I'm not sure the root cause but it seems it fails around cython stuff. https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/blob/master/chainercv/utils/bbox/_nms_gpu_post.pyx
Did you install cython? if not please try setup cython install and try installing chainercv again.

Also, if you can try in Linux environment, it is more easy way to avoid this issue.

Comment: We need to install Visual Build Tools 2015 version. That has solved the error that I have been getting.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying on admin ? else please follow below steps
open cmd using `Ctrl + r` then type `cmd` and try to install from there

```
pip install ChainerCV
```